# Getting error while running npm start in expo project

Tags: android, react-native, expo

**`Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: failed to install /home/spinny/.expo/android-apk-cache/Exponent-2.15.4.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1162803835.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]`**

This is the error i am getting while running npm start in project. I just created this project using expo but it shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with Expo in the managed workflow or with react-native (bare workflow) ?

Do you want to open your project with a physical device or an emulator ?

If you are working with your device, are you connected to the same network as your computer ?